# C# -LINQ- Extension Method

Tags: c#, linq

What is the extension method equivalent of the following LINQ?

```
var qry = from a in context.A_Collections
          from b in context.B_Collections
          where a.PK == b.PK
          select 
        new {
              A_key = a.PK, 
              A_Value = a.Value,
              B_Key = b.PK,
              B_value = b.value
            };
```

I mean

(incomplete)

```
var query = context.A_Collections.
                Where(
                      a => a.PK == context.B_Collections.Select(b => b.PK)).
                    Select(
                            x => new { 
                                      A_key = a.Pk,
                                      A_Value = a.Value,
                                      B_Key = b.PK,
                                      B_value = b.value
                                     }
                           );
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Subsequent "from" clauses translate to [`SelectMany`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534631.aspx) calls:

```
var qry = context.A_Collections
                 .SelectMany(a => context.B_Collections,
                             (a, b) => new { a, b })
                 .Where(x => x.a.PK == x.b.PK)
                 .Select(x => new { A_key = x.a.PK,
                                    A_value = x.a.Value,
                                    B_key = x.b.PK,
                                    B_value = x.b.Value });
```

The "x" bit is due to the introduction of a *transparent identifier*.

Note that a call to [`Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.join.aspx) may be more efficient than using `SelectMany` (depending on the exact situation), but this is the more direct translation of the query you started with.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're trying to do a join, so it would be:

```
var query = context.A_Collections.Join(
 context.B_Collections,
 a => a.PK,
 b => b.PK,
 (a, b) => new {
  A_key = a.PK,
  A_value = a.Value,
  B_Key = b.PK,
  B_value = b.value
 });
```

EDIT: As Jon Skeet points out however, the actual translation done by the compiler will use SelectMany although using group will probably be more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

It would be something like:

```
context.A_Collections.Include("B")
.Where(a => a.PK == a.B.PK)
.Select(a => 
     new {A_key = a.PK, 
          A_Value = a.Value, 
          B_Key = a.B.PK, 
          b_value = a.B.value } );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using Resharper this will help you to convert all Linq queries in Linq Methods if you prefer that.